# Facebook Graph API me/accounts returns empty Json data array

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am getting the following empty data array for https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXXXXXX:

STEP 1: - Get the CODE using Oauth URL

STEP 2: - Get the access token using the above CODE in Oauth access token URL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add all the required permissions as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340626/12326605

Answer (score 2):

What permissions does the access_token have?  (see https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)  You may not have requested the correct ones.

Comment: I have the following output but me/accounts return empty array:   App ID:      11111111111 : MyAppName
User ID: 12345678900 : FB user name
Issued:         1325555945 : 5:59 pm Jan 2 2012
Expires: Never
Valid:  True
Origin:  Web
Scopes:  create_note manage_pages offline_access photo_upload publish_stream read_stream share_item status_update video_upload

Comment: That's very strange.  You have the permission of `manage_pages` which is required for `me/accounts`.  Have you tried running the me/accounts in the Graph API Explorer tool to see if it returns the same thing?

Comment: yes. I tried in graph explorer as well and returns empty JSON data array only. Is there anything to do with user roles?

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_html($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

function get_json($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($data);
}

if ($_GET['type'] == "page") {

    $pages =
        get_json("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?fields=id,picture,name&access_token=$token")->data;

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $page->picture;
        $page->name;
        $page->id;
    }
}
```