# Facebook API me/accounts returns not all pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Facebooks Graph Api 3.2 (newest).
I have a valid token and run "/me/accounts" via Graph-Explorer.
There listed  41 of my pages. But  I manage 43 pages. 2 are missing.
For these missing 2, I also have the correct rights "analyze" like for the 41 others...
Also, there is NO paging-problem. If I run graph-explorer with "?limit=50", there are only 41....
Does anyone have a tip where the 2 missing pages are?

regards

Comment: Try the steps describe in here, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/347345726022992/

Comment: thanks very much. that helped. Exactly these 2 pages are not marked in my settings (Business-Integrations -> AppName -> Liste of pages -> show all -> scrollToBottom)

Comment: @misorude this is a far more helpful comment than just in answer to the OP question. Just saved a lot of frustration for why a reporting app works with one page, but not another.

Answer (score 20):

In my case, it was listing all the pages except some business pages so I had to add `business_management` permission and generate a new user access token.

Permission I used to generate token:- `pages_show_list`, `business_management`, `pages_read_engagement`, `pages_manage_metadata`, `pages_read_user_content`, `pages_manage_ads`, `pages_manage_posts`, `pages_manage_engagement`

If in case you are not seeing all your pages, the issue might be related to Granular permission as described in this meta thread:-
[User can't see all his pages using the me/accounts endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/347345726022992)
You need to grant permission for pages to access data. Go to Facebook settings (either Apps and Websites or Business Integrations) by clicking below links:-

- [Apps and Websites](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)
- [Business Integrations](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=business_tools)

You will see all the Apps you have created or have access. In my case, it was for Business Integration. Click on 'View and edit' for the respective app. In a window that opens, you can scroll down to the section "Show a list of the Pages you manage". Here, you need to put a checkmark next to all of the pages that you wish to have on the list.

[image: ![enter image description here]

For details information about these permissions, you can check:

- [Facebook Pages API - Overview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview#permissions)
- [Meta - Permissions Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference#reference-business_management)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, I think this answer does not work any more, even if it somehow hints in the right direction, i.e. it is an issue of granular permissions.

The only place where I was seemingly able to add access to all pages was from the Graph API explorer.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Select your app from the drop down menu, and then from the "User or Page" dropdown select: "Get page access token"

You will be asked to re-authenticate, and then you will be able to choose between:

- "Opt in to all current and future Pages"
- or select from a list of your pages

Then you will see you'll have more permissions in the list:

- `pages_show_list`
- `pages_read_engagement`
- `ads_read`
- `read_insights`

As suggested in other answers here, you may need to add other permissions here. In particular, if you are managing pages through business manager, you probably will need to add also `business_management`. You will be prompted which business managers you want to give it access to, and then all pages managed through those business managers should also appear.

Do remember to regenerate your token after adding permissions to actually get access.