# Facebook Graph API: Query on the GET /me/accounts endpoint returns empty data

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

**CONTEXT :**
I am writing an iOS app which displays the number of followers of any Instagram account, after the user enters the name. The program launches a function refreshed every 20 seconds to actualise the number of followers.
At some point, it appears that the app is not able to retrieve the number of followers anymore. Indeed, I can clearly see that after several queries, the app is not anymore able to access the source code of the Insta page, but reaches the Login page. This is why I installed Facebook SDK, followed Apple procedures, and also received an access token.

**PROBLEM :**
In the Facebook Graph API Explorer, I type the following query:
`curl -i -X GET \ "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/accounts?access_token={access-token}"` (with my user access token).

Finally, what I get is empty data:

```
{"data": []}
```

Why is it empty as I am connected to my app ?

**SOURCE :**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/

Comment: What is your question and how is this about programming?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for the reply. Right, my question is "Why is it empty as I am connected to my app ?". And for you second question, I don't see what you want me to say...

Comment: i had same issue and fix it with that solution - > [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391366/facebook-api-me-accounts-returns-not-all-pages/76340626#76340626)