# Why is Instagram Graph API not returning any data for me/accounts to get user page ID?

Tags: facebook, instagram

I am trying out Instagram Graph API for the first time. I want to get the user page ID in hopes to then be able to get instagram business account ID. My problem is when using the Graph tool provided on the website for my app, it returns nothing when I put me/accounts. I saw elsewhere that me/accounts would return various data, including what I am looking for, but it is empty.

I've had trouble finding updated documentation for the correct permissions needed for me/accounts. Some permissions just don't seem to be available anymore. I've tried many permissions but nothing works for what I need. Here is what I have: pages_show_list, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments, instagram_manage_insights, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content. Also yes I do have a business instagram account, and it is linked with my Facebook account.

Comment: also I set up Facebook login

Comment: Did you check this answer:- [Facebook API me/accounts returns not all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340626/12326605)?

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem. It doesn't work with V17.0 but is working with V16.0

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer: Use v16.0**

Newly created Facebook Pages or Instagram accounts are no longer automatically accessible due to their association with business assets. To access these resources, you typically need the **'business_management'** permission. However, it's important to note that obtaining this permission might require approval.

If you don't want to go through the process of getting **'business_management'** permission, you can still work with these resources using **'v16.0'** of the API. According to the Meta team, this version allows you to access and interact with Pages and Instagram accounts without the need for the **'business_management'** permission. This change simplifies the access requirements for these resources on the platform.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/847967777040668/