# Instagram Graph API returning empty dataset

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Similar version of this question I saw posted was from 2013... Going to try again to see if anyone can point me in the right direction.

I am attempting to use the Graph API Explorer to create an access token for my application to view my pages using `me/accounts`. However, every time I try this, it returns an empty data set. I have chosen `pages_show_list` and `instagram_basic` as permissions and it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I'm doing:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Select my application from the drop-down menu.
Add the permissions > Generate Access Token

Submit `GET /me/accounts`
I get :

{

"data": [   ]

}

Thanks!

I've tried unlinking the fb and ig pages, unlinking the fb page from my fb profile, turning my business ig account into a private one and back again, and adding more permissions, and still getting the empty data field.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340626/22212322)!

Turns out I needed to add `business_management` as a permission as well...