# Facebook API me/accounts returns nothing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

when I ask to run "me/accounts" it returns nothing

`{ "data": [ ] }`

i followed many videos on yt and i didn't find any solution. The only thing that is returned to me is what is seen in the figure without any data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVyGg.png)

Comment: Add all the required permissions as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340626/12326605