# Facebook Graph API v19 endpoint me/accounts returns empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i am using the Facebook Graph API v19 and try to access the data through me/accounts it returns empty json. I try to generate a Page access token but that token doesn't work too. I already have the pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement and business_management permissions and i still cannot do it.

It is not the first time i am doing this and with the other apps i can get access to the pages feed, but not this time, it keeps returning empty. I even tried writing the actual facebook page id to access its feed but it says the token is invalid. It appears to not generate the page access token correctly.

Does anybody else had this problem? If so, were you able to solve it?

Comment: Do you have all the permissions added as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340626/12326605?

Comment: I didn't need all those permissions. I then was able to get an access_token by having access to the page id and my user token. Then with the endpoint <page_id>?access_token=<user_token> i was able to generate the page access token. Thanks for the answer.